# Bash- How to convert non-alphanumerical character to "_"

Tags: regex, bash, string

I am trying to store user input in a variable and clean that variable in order to keep only alphanumerical caract + some others (I mean [a-zA-Z0-9-_]).

I tried using this but it isn't exhaustive :

```
SERVICE_NAME=$(echo $SERVICE_NAME | tr A-Z a-z | tr ' ' _ | tr \' _ | tr \" _)
```

Do you have some help for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ echo 'asd!@QCW@@D' | tr A-Z a-z | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/_/g'
asd__qcw__d
```

I would use `sed` for this and use the `^` (not) operator in your set of valid characters and replace everything else with an underscore. The above shows the syntax with the output.

And, as a bonus, if you want to replace a run of invalid characters with one underscore, just add `+` to your regular expression (and use the `-r` switch to `sed` to make it use extended regular expressions:

```
$ echo 'asd!@QCW@@D' | tr A-Z a-z | sed -r 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/_/g'
asd_qcw_d
```

Comment: If cross-platform compatibility is an issue, remember that BSD's `sed` uses `-E` to enable extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 17):

Bash's string substitution is a fine thing: ${var//pat/rep}

```
val='Foo$%!*@BAR###baZ'
echo ${val//[^a-zA-Z_-]/_}
Foo_____BAR___baZ
```

A small explanation: The slash introduces a search/replace, a little like in sed (where it just delimits patterns). But you use a single slash for one replacement:

```
val='Foo$%!*@BAR###baZ'
echo ${val/[^a-zA-Z_-]/_}
Foo_%!*@BAR###baZ
```

Two slashes // mean replace all. Uncommon, but it has some logic, multiple slashes to mean multiple replace (please excuse my poor English).

And note how the $ is separated from the variable, but it is hard to modify a literal constant this way (which would be nice for testing). Modifying $1 isn't a no-brainer as well, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can all be done in 1 single sed command like this:

```
echo 'Foo$%!*@BAR###baZ' | sed -e 's/[A-Z]/\L&/g' -e 's/[^a-z0-9\-]/_/g'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
foo_____bar___baz
```

Answer (score 0):

perl way:

```
perl -ple 's/[^\w\-]/_/g'
```

pure bash way

```
a='foo-BAR_123,.:goo'
echo ${a//[^[:alnum:]-]/_}
```

produces:

```
foo-BAR_123___goo
```